# File name comparison with underscore

Tags: macros, strings

We have tested `\filename{XYZ-2100011}` and `\include{XYZ-2100011}` both input tex file name matched or not, otherwise we passed error messages in the macros.

In my cases how to support input file name contains underscore "XYZ_2100011".

E.g, `\filename{XYZ_2100011}` and `\include{XYZ_2100011}`

Please find MWE file as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\filename#1{\gdef\@filename{#1}}

\def\include#1{\relax
  \def\@tmp{#1}%
  \ifx\@filename\@tmp
    \ifnum\@auxout=\@partaux
      \@latex@error{\string\include\space cannot be nested}\@eha
    \else \@include#1 \fi
  \else
    \@latex@error{\string Filenames don't match}\@eha
  \fi}

\makeatother

\filename{XYZ-2100011}%it should be XYZ_2100011

\begin{document}

\include{XYZ-2100011}%it should be XYZ_2100011

\end{document}
```

Comment: you shouldn't redefine \include like this. That is *not* the current definition, and it will destroy the hooks.

Comment: what is the intention of this code, please show an example (prefereably without the broken `\include` definition) that shows the problem with `_` what error did you get?

Answer (score 4):

With a current latex you can add your test with the `include/before` hook:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\filename[1]{\edef\mypackage@filename{\detokenize{#1}}}
\newcommand\mypackage@filename{}
\AddToHook{include/before}{%
  \ifx\CurrentFile\mypackage@filename 
  \else
  \PackageError{mypackage}{filename '\mypackage@filename' doesn't match with \CurrentFile}{}%
  \fi}
\makeatother  
\filename{XYZ_2100011}

\begin{document}

\include{XYZ_2100011}
\include{XYZ_2100011-X}
\end{document}
```

Comment: \AddToHook{} showing Undefined control sequence?

Comment: Then you don't have a current latex.

Comment: Downloaded last year MiKTeX 2.9, This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (MiKTeX 2.9.7250 64-bit) (preloaded format=latex 2021.6.28)  29 JUN 2021 18:06

Comment: Well things can change in a year. The hooks have been added in october last year.

Comment: Is there any package need to add?

Comment: The hooks are in the LaTeX format. You will have to update latex if you want to use it. Check with the miktex console (admin *and* user mode) which updates are pending).